# File is not showing as locked in GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab, locking, git-lfs

I am trying to push a locked file from my local repository to remote repository in GitLab.
I used following commands.

```
git lfs lock Test.txt

$ git lfs locks
Test.txt        ChkBuk  ID:1327625
 git push -uf origin main
```

But after pushing to remote repository, I can see the file but not shown as 'Locked'. I can still edit the file.
Can anybody please explain where I got wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/docs/man/git-lfs-lock.adoc "*…blocking attempts **by other users** to update the given path.*" — emphasize mine.